# Pivot rows into column using DAX code in DAX Studio

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

[image]

Can anyone help me with code to do a "transpose" function in DAX using DAX Studio (From Image 1 to Image 2)

Image 1
Image 2

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Table 2 = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[AreaName]),
    "Jan", CALCULATE( SUM('Table'[AreaCount]) , TREATAS( {"Jan"},'Table'[Month])),
     "Feb", CALCULATE( SUM('Table'[AreaCount]) , TREATAS( {"Feb"},'Table'[Month]))
)
```

[image]